# .animate() method to use second time

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want to animate a side-panel. The first action is done, where i click a button and the side panel collapses or decreases in `height`. Now i want the side panel to regain its `width` on clicking the button again, which i am not able to accomplish.

Here is the thing i made:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.collaps').click(function(){    
        $('#adminmenuback').animate({width:"30px"});    
    }); 
});
```

Please try to answer using the same `.animate` method only, not any other like slideToggle and so on... Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you create this in fiddle

Answer (score 1):

I know you're looking for an answer that utilizes `$.animate`, but have you considered using CSS3 transitions? This approach keeps your JS behavioral and moves the styles into CSS.

```
.button {
    background-color: purple;
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
    width: 200px;
}

.expanded {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 400px;
}

<div class='button'>click me</div>

$('.button').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dz8N/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the panel width and do the animation accordingly

```
$('.collaps').click(function(){
    if ($('#adminmenuback').width() != 30) // if it's not the minimal width then collapse
    {
        $('#adminmenuback').animate({width:"30px"});
    }
    else // if it is minimal then enlarge
    {
        $('#adminmenuback').animate({width: "300px"}); //change the width to what you need
    }
});
```

Edit: if you are using padding you might need `.outerWidth()` instead or `.width()`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/slash197/YABp2/)

Comment: hi slash197, your code appears to be right, but its not working due to some reason

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the animate method only, then you can set a Flag which will tell you whether to hide or show suck as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var showFlag=1
  $('.collaps').click(function() {
   if(showFlag==1){
     $('#adminmenuback').animate({width:"30px"});
      showFlag=0;
   }else{
     $('#adminmenuback').animate({width:"-30px"});
     showFlag=1;
   }     
  });
});
```

Comment: there's no toggle syntax with two function arguments, you may be referring to [this one here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) but it has been deprecated since 1.8 and that's not how you would use it

Comment: still that's not how you would implement it for this case, the toggle would go instead of click and if you're going to suggest a deprecated method you should add a note that expresses that fact in your answer

Comment: changed answer based on OP's requirement